# Avoiding await in for loop in testafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

I have a written a test that loops through drop down options and sets value based on options. During the process, I have to also evaluate if the index is indeed set for which my code is -

```
    test(`Select all available options`, async (browser) => {
      const audioDevicelist = Selector(
        '#__next > div > main > div.Home_toolbar__JY_RL > div.Home_deviceControls__nQw4V > select:nth-child(2)'
      );
      const setSelectedIndex = ClientFunction(
        (index) => {
          audioDevicelist().selectedIndex = index;
        },
        { dependencies: { audioDevicelist } }
      );
      await browser.wait(3000);
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        await setSelectedIndex(i);
        await browser.expect(audioDevicelist.selectedIndex).eql(i);
         
        }
      }
      
    });

This works, but I wanted to avoid the await inside a loop. So I tried -

if (audioDevicelist.selectedIndex === i) {
        let ops += 1;
      } else {
        console.log('Sorry');
      }
```

But somehow the if statement is not validating while below statement
satisfies and passes the test.

```
await browser.expect(audioDevicelist.selectedIndex).eql(i);
```

Any pointers? I just wanted to remove await inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get any properties from the `Selector` result directly because the result of the `Selector` is a special asynchronous function and you should run it to get [DOMNodeState](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402670/reference/test-api/domnodestate). After that, you can get this property from the node state. But in any case, you should use `await` to get `DOMNodeState`.